# Finding displacement from a given force using Newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

How are we able to solve for displacement if we have 2 or more given forces, the time it takes, and the acceleration.

Newton's second law: F=MA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force is often used to find acceleration. If you already know the acceleration, then you can ignore the forces. Try using: $x = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$.

Comment: You should specify that this is only for constant acceleration in one dimension.